# jQuery Boilerplate - Losing Access to "this" Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-boilerplate

I'm trying to write my first plugin using [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com). The issue I'm having is that I lose access to the `this` scope as soon as I try to handle an event, due, I assume, to [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). It seems like would be a common use case for [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com), so I'm guessing that I'm going about it incorrectly.

I found two similar questions here on SO:

1. [jQuery plugin object: attached an event handler via .on() and now have a scope issue of this. (the main plugin object)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26390152/244826) - Has no answer
2. [Javascript scoping Issue using JQuery Boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20824364/244826) - Doesn't answer my question

I've created a minimal sample to demonstrate the issue.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

**PLUGIN**

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    var pluginName = 'elementValueLog',
            defaults = {};

    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.$element = $(element);
        this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    }

    $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
        init: function() {
            this.$element.on('click', this.doLog);
        },
        doLog: function() {
            // HERE: I can't figure out how to access the Plugin "this" scope
            // I want to be able to use "element", "$element", "settings", etc.
            console.log(this.$element.val().trim());
        }
    });

    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
        this.each(function() {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery, window, document, undefined));
```

**USE PLUGIN**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').elementValueLog();
});
```

---

**SOLUTION**

I would have preferred to add this as an answer, but being marked as "duplicate" is preventing that. After trying several methods shown in the answers on the other post, I found a solution. I personally think my question is specific enough to stand on its own, because the "canonical" answer on the other post is quite broad.

For [browsers that support `bind`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/), the `init` function can be changed like this:

```
init: function() {
    this.$element.on('click', this.doLog.bind(this));
},
```

Because I need to support IE 8, I will be using [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/):

```
init: function() {
    this.$element.on('click', $.proxy(this.doLog, this));
},
```

The `doLog` function can then reference `this.element`, `this.$element`, `this.settings`, etc.

Based on the answer from [Jeff Watkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1423274/jeff-watkins):

```
init: function() {
    var plugin = this;
    var doLog = function() {
        console.log(plugin.$element.val().trim());
    };
    this.$element.on('click', doLog);
},
```

This solution has the benefit of preserving the `this` context while giving access to the Plugin's `this` context.

Comment: So this has been marked as a duplicate of another post, but I don't understand how to apply the solution that's presented in that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this" is contextual to where you are in the stack, so "this" in an event is actually the event, if that makes sense. It's a common programming concept.

I often use a cached version of "this" (i.e. the caller) to use if you need to call something on it.

i.e.

```
$.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    var caller = this;
    this.each(function() {
        if (!$.data(caller, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
```

Comment: How would you change the `doLog` function? That's where I am unable to access the `Plugin`'s `element`, `$element`, and `settings` properties.

Comment: The same way as above... although your proxy answer works as well IIRC.

Comment: Because you gave an answer that works, I'm going to accept it. I've also added your answer as one of the possible solutions.